# How are char[] interpreted as const std::strings in arguments

Tags: c++, string

I recently realized that I can do this:

```
void someFunc(const std::string &str)
{
   //content
}

...
someFunc("Hello World"); //this works
```

I'm wondering how that works and why it works.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works because `std::string` has a constructor from `const char *` that is not marked `explicit`.  The C++ compiler will insert a call to one such constructor (per argument) if necessary to make the arguments match.

Answer (score 4):

You example actually demonstrates the opposite: a const char array is interpreted as `std::string`. (BTW, a string literal is not a `const char *`, it is a `const char[N]` - a char array, not a char pointer).

The reason it work is that a char array is implicitly convertible to `std::string` by means of `std::string`s conversion constructor. The compiler performs the conversion for you, in full agreement with overload resolution rules of C++ language.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a character literal is NOT a `const char *`. (Actually, it's not a `const char[N]` either -- it's a `char[N]` -- character literals are non-`const` even though they must be treated as `const`...) It amazes me how many programmers get this wrong.

Comment: @Billy: Huh? §2.13.4/1: "An ordinary string literal has type “array of n const char”".

Comment: @Billy ONeal: In this case you happen to be the one who gets it wrong. String literals were `char[N]` arrays in *C* language. C++ is different. In *C++* string literals are `const char[N]` arrays. The reason you can initialize `char *` with string literals in C++ is a dedicated (and deprecated) conversion introduced in C++ specifically for that purpose. (There was no need for such conversion in C). Of course, string literals are non-mutable in both languages.

Comment: @AndreyT: That's what I meant by "you have to treat them as `const` " -- you're not allowed to modify them but their type is effectively non- `const` as a result of the conversion. It's defined as if the data was `const` in order to take advantage of other parts in the standard which refer to `const` data (namely that you can't modify the data). But the *type` is effectively non- `const`.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Not true. In C++ the type of the string literal is effectively `const`. In order to use the deprecated const-removing conversion you have to deliberately create the circumstances that would invoke that conversion (assign/initialize a `char *` object by a literal). In all other circumstances `const` is preserved. For one example, when you do `throw "Hello!"` an exception of type `const char *` is thrown (not of type `char *`). And this exception will not be caught by a `catch (char *)` clause. For another example, the `char *p = "Hello!" + 1;` initialization will not compile.

Comment: @AnT if the type in c was  non const why was  it in read only section . and you cannot change it?

Answer (score 3):

This works because the compiler creates a *temporary object* of type `std::string` in the caller, before calling `someFunc()`.

The compiled code will be roughly equivalent to the following:

```
{
    std::string _temp1("Hello World");
    someFunc(_temp1);
}
```

(I put the code in braces to show that the `_temp1` destructor will be executed immediately after the call to `someFunc()` returns.)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by [implicit conversion in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867462/c-implicit-conversions)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is backwards... a `const char*` becomes a `std::string` when used as an argument, and this is because there is an implicit conversion (a constructor with one argument) from `const char*` to `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the reverse: 'how are const char*s interpreted as std::strings' ? Well, there is a constructor of the std::string class that converts a const char* into a std::string

An actual constructor can be found in /usr/include/c++/4.3.4/bits/basic_string.h

```
 /**
  *  @brief  Construct string as copy of a C string.
  *  @param  s  Source C string.
  *  @param  a  Allocator to use (default is default allocator).
  */
  basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc());
```

Comment: Well, that's where the actual constructor is on **your** machine, but that certainly doesn't mean where it is on the OP's machine. My machine, for example, doesn't have a path called `/usr` -- the equivalent would be `C:\Users` -- yet `std::basic_string` certainly exists for me too.

Comment: true, but he wanted to understand how it is defined.