# Default assignment operator for template class with different template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

When compiling the following:

```
template <class T>
class Number
{
    private:
        T num;
    public:
        Number() {}
        Number( T n ) : num(n) {}
        operator T() const { return num; }
};

int main()
{
    Number<int> n=5;
    Number<char> c=4;
    int i;

    c=int(5);
    i=n;
    c=n;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gets stuck at the third assignment saying there is no match for `operator=` in `c=n`. Shouldn't `n` get converted to `int`, which in turn will be assigned to `c`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard, at most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single value. Here, you are expecting the compiler to apply the constructor for `Number<char>` and the conversion operator for `Number<int>`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/867804/677131.

Answer (score 2):

That's because there is no `int` operator when your templated class is constructed with the templated type as `char`.

You actually don't have an assigment operator here, only a constructor and a type operator. This means your compiler would likely have put in a default one probably along the lines of:

```
Number<T>& operator=( Number<T>& rhs );
```

You should implement your own assignment operator, this should fix your problem. A generic solution could be as follows, but relies on a valid assignment between the types.

```
template <typename T, typename V>
class Number
{
    private:
        T num;
    public:
        Number() {}
        Number( T n ) : num(n) {}
        operator T() const { return num; }
        operator=( V& rhs ){ num = rhs; // etc }
};
```

You also need to make your class constructor `explicit` to avoid implicit conversion (unless that is what you want).

Comment: `templated class is constructed as a char` - I have big problems trying to figure out what you mean there. A class that is constructed _as a_ `char`?

Comment: `n` is constructed as an `int`. It has an `int` operator. `c` can be assigned `int`s. BTW, it doesn't work the other way either, so the problem is not trying to assign `int` to `char`.

Comment: Can you please clarify? I don't understand what the problem is.