# Conversion and upcasting

Tags: c++, reference, implicit-conversion, upcasting

I want to fully understand conversions, i.e. to be sure I know when does a function call would cause an implicit conversion, and when would it cause a compilation error.
I've learnt that a conversion may be done if and only if there is a singular way to convert the variable with up to two steps from the following list (sorted by priority):

```
1. Exact match
2. Promotion
3. Conversion
4. User defined conversion
```

Where, the way I understood it (you may correct me), is that promotion is a conversion of primitives into bigger primitive types, such as short to int, float to double, etc; Conversion is any conversion between primitives which isn't promotion, such as int to char, etc; And user defined conversions are conversions of classes using conversion constructors and conversion operators.
Now, I also know that inheritance means and Is-A relationship, meaning that a derived class is base class, and so sending a derived class to a function which expects a reference to a base class should work. Combining the two concepts above, we should get that the following example I wrote, should work:

```
class C {};
class D: public C
{
public:
D(int x){}
};
void f(C& c) {}
f(3);
```

Since D can be converted-to from int, and a D is a C. But this code isn't being compiled. Why is that? How can the contradiction be resolved? Can you shed some light on the matter? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The code doesn't compile because the conversion would create a temporary, which can't bind to a non-`const` reference.

If you pass the parameter by `const` reference (or by value, but I'm not suggesting you do that), it will work.

You also need a conversion constructor in the base class (explained below).

```
class C {
public:
   C(int x){}
};
class D: public C
{
public:
   D(int x):C(x){}
};

void f(const C& c) {}
f(3);
```

This is because **implicit conversion only applies a maximum of one times**. In your case, there is a direct conversion from `int -> D` and one from `D -> C`, so an `int` can't implicitly be converted to `C`.

Comment: @Als I didn't see the base class. If he has a conversion ctor in the base class, it will.

Comment: You are totally right about the const thing. But are you sure about the "implicit conversion only applies a maximum of one times"? I've been taught that an implicit conversion applies up to two times.

Comment: @Idan yes. It can't (logically). Any restriction greater than 1 would yield ambiguities.

Comment: @Idan see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867462/c-implicit-conversions

Comment: from the link you've attached, it seems like only 1 *user-defined* conversion is allowed, but more native conversions are allowed. So in this case it should work (with my example with an added 'const'), and it does.

Comment: It doesn't work by value though and I don't understand why. From what I've understood it should work, as D can be converted to from int, and D can be sliced into C using the copy constructor.

Comment: @Idan at most one **user-defined** implicit conversion is allowed per conversion sequence. Many implicit conversions involve more than one "elementary" conversion, f.ex. `Der*` to `const Base*` involves a derived-to-base and a non-const-to-const conversion.