# Argument conversion in the presence of function templates

Tags: c++, function, templates, arguments, type-conversion

I have a set of function templates that depend on two integers. These need to be instantiated, except that one of the function arguments needs to be converted. A conversion operator is provided for the purpose. However the compiler (VS 2013 express preview) refuses to recognize the possibility of conversion. See the code below.

In conversion_op.h

```
template<int N>
class Proxy
{
};

template<int M, int N>
void func(const Proxy<M>& p1, const Proxy<N>& p2)
{
}

typedef Proxy<1> SpecialProxy;

class Orig
{
    SpecialProxy P;

public:
    operator SpecialProxy() const
    {
        return P;
    }
};
```

In conversion_op.cpp

```
#include "conversion_op.h"

//template void func(const SpecialProxy&, const SpecialProxy&);
//template void func(const SpecialProxy&, const Proxy<2>&);
//template void func(const Proxy<2>&, const SpecialProxy&);
//template void func(const Proxy<2>&, const Proxy<2>&);

int Test()
{
    Orig a;

    SpecialProxy p1;
    Proxy<2> p2;

    func<1,1>(a, p1); //OK
    func<1,2>(a, p2); //OK
    func<1,1>(p1, a); //OK
    func<2,1>(p2, a); //OK

    func(a, p1); //Error
    func(a, p2); //Error
    func(p1, a); //Error
    func(p2, a); //Error
}
```

The error is:
"could not deduce template argument for 'const Proxy &' from 'Orig'. Please see declaration of func."

I tried replacing

```
operator SpecialProxy() const;
```

by

```
operator const SpecialProxy&() const;
```

but the error remains the same.

Also tried explicitly instantiating the needed function (commented out code in conversion_op.cpp), but no luck.

Any insight is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Haven't been able to find a solution yet. Can anybody help. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that [C++ does not allow implicit conversion when deducing template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867462/c-implicit-conversions/868398#868398).

When the compiler tries to instantiate `func(a, p1)` for instance, it can promptly deduce N -> 1, but has no value for M, nor is it allowed deduce it out of the implicit conversion of `a` to `Proxy<1>` as defined in `Orig`.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that if I want this implicit conversion, I would have to write explicit overloads for all the types that I want? In other words, I cannot expect function templates to "interact" in any way with implicit conversions?

Comment: @skm unfortunately not as for c++11.