# Why can't I implicitly construct an object given a suitable constructor when passing to an argument?

Tags: c++

In the below example, why can't I simply pass a `string` to the `printFoo()`?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
  Foo(const Foo &foo) : str(foo.str) {}
  Foo(string str) : str(str) {}

  string str;
};

void printFoo(Foo foo) {
  cout << foo.str << endl;
}

int main() {
  Foo foo("qux");
  printFoo(foo); // OK

  printFoo("qix"); // error: no matching function for call to 'printFoo'

  return 0;
}
```

For whatever reason, I had in my head that a constructor would automatically be determined and used in order to construct an object.

Why can't I do this, but I can pass a `char[n]` constant to an argument accepting a `std::string`, for example?

Comment: In your example, you don't have a suitable constructor. Correct constructor would be `Foo(const char*)`.

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen but `std::string` has a suitable constructor.

Comment: There would be two implicit conversions involved: 1. to std::string; 2. to Foo. C++ does at most one.

Comment: @DieterLücking does the spec limit this specifically to 1?

Comment: @DieterLücking mind making an answer with the spec reference so I can accept it?

Comment: already answered with reference, here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867462/c-implicit-conversions

Comment: Note that now (in C++14) you can write `printFoo ("qux"s):` after using the proper namespace in scope somewhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There would be two implicit conversions involved:

1. to `std::string`
2. to `Foo`

C++ does at most one:

From 4 Standard conversions (N3337)

> Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning.
>   Clause 4 enumerates the full set of such conversions. A standard
>   conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in the
>   following order:
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set:
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, and
>   function-to-pointer conversion.
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the
>   following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral
>   conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral
>   conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to member conversions, and
>   boolean conversions.
>
> — Zero or one qualification conversion.

Also 12.3 Conversions (N3337)

> 1 Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and
>   by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined
>   conversions and are used for implicit type conversions (Clause 4), for
>   initialization (8.5), and for explicit type conversions (5.4, 5.2.9).
>
> 2 User-defined conversions are applied only where they are unambiguous
>   (10.2, 12.3.2). Conversions obey the access control rules (Clause 11).
>   Access control is applied after ambiguity resolution (3.4).
>
> [...]
>
> 4 **At most one user-defined**
>   **conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied**
>   **to a single value.**

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 8):

According to the C++ standard *§12.3/4 Conversions [class.conv]:*

> At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion
>   function) is implicitly applied to a single value.

Thus, the compiler is not allowed to apply two conversions in a row. That is, firstly from `const char[4]` to `std::string` and secondly from `std::string` to `Foo`.

For this to work you would need to define an additional constructor:

```
Foo(char const *str_) : str(str_) {}
```

Answer (score 5):

Thats because the compiler is allowed to consider one conversion.

To do what you need to do the compiler would need to plant two conversions.

```
printFoo("qix");

// Actually needs.
printFoo(Foo(std::string("qix")));
```

If you change this so you pass a string it will work.

```
printFoo(std::string("qix"));
```

The main reason behind all this is string literals have the type `char const[<size>]` **NOT** `std::string`

Comment: Since C++11 you may write `printFoo("qix"s);`  (with appropriate include)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, problem is that 2 conversions needed. You may use `s` literal to convert string literal to actual `std::string`

```
printFoo("qix"s);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/mKlnbp)