# How to directly call conversion operator?

Tags: c++

```
struct Bob
{
    template<class T>
    void operator () () const
    {
        T t;
    }

    template<class T>
    operator T () const
    {
        T t;
        return t;
    }
};
```

I can directly call Bob's operator() like this

```
Bob b;
b.operator()<int>();
```

How to directly call the conversion operator with a specific template parameter like this?

```
Bob b;
std::string s = b.???<std::string>();
```

It's not possible to use static_cast

```
Bob b;
std::string s = static_cast<std::string>(b);
```

http://ideone.com/FoBKp7

`error: call of overloaded ‘basic_string(Bob&)’ is ambiguous`

**Question**
How to call directly with template parameter OR it's not possible. I know there are workarounds using a wrapping function.

Comment: hah, nice try. No, not possible as far as I'm aware. that's why I suggested using a real function. Besides, what's the point of making it a conversion function if you're going to call it like a regular one?

Comment: @Dave The same for the other operators. A backup in case you want to for some reason.

Comment: And that, children, is why implicit conversions are evil.

Comment: What's wrong with `b.operator std::string()`?

Comment: @gx_ Nothing, I assume. Write an answer..

Comment: Or even `b.operator decltype(s)();` (which I was admittedly surprised worked in clang). Then again, so does simple `std::string s = b;` so I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Well there you are. Now I've learned two things about cast functions today. (I'll likely never use either because they're ugly but hey, knowledge)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can call it directly (explicitly) like this:

```
Bob b;
std::string s = b.operator std::string();
```

but it's not "with a specific template parameter" (but there's no need for).

See also [WhozCraig's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539040/how-to-directly-call-conversion-operator/18539328#comment27268025_18539040)

Comment: Fwiw, `std::string s = b;` also works (at least on my rig). But thats beginning to paddle away from the original question at a pretty rapid rate =)

Comment: @WhozCraig Of course (the purpose of a conversion operator is to enable implicit conversion after all). But I linked to your other comment that adds `decltype(s)` :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a helper function:

```
template< typename T >
T explicit_cast( T t ) { return t; }

int main()
{
    Bob b;
    std::string s = explicit_cast<std::string>(b);
}
```

Comment: *cough*... value parameter ... *cough*.

Comment: I want to know if it is possible or not to call directly.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think in this case a by-value parameter is better than a by-const-reference as it allows more optimization. Or do you think otherwise?

Comment: I think *both* value and reference should be supplied via overload, but then again, I'm not sure I'd ever find myself in a position to do *either* =)

Comment: Your "explicit_cast" resembles [`implicit_cast`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/863761) (which is better defined)