# How to use bool member function in is_integral_v?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, type-traits

From [this cppreference link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral), `is_integral` has `bool` as a member function. How to use it? I could understand other members, and am able to code a simple example as follows. But how to use the `bool` member function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << boolalpha;
    // member constants
    cout << is_integral_v<int> << endl; // prints true

    // member functions
    // operator bool ?
    
    // operator()
    cout << is_integral<float>() << endl; // prints false

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539040/how-to-directly-call-conversion-operator/18539328

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: You're already using it here `is_integral<float>()` implicitly.

Comment: Just a heads up stop using : "using namespace". It is very explained very well by Jason Turner, the reasons may surprise you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8

Comment: @PepijnKramer for the sake of brevity I used that.

Comment: Brevity is what will kill maintainability in the long run... won't pass my code reviews. 
My take on it : even in hobby projects keep using recommended practices so they become second nature. And typeing std:: is like what .5 seconds extra work?

Comment: @PepijnKramer While I agree with you, that video is actually a poor reference. Starting out with "we don't do this because it has been agreed a long time", simply repeating that a lot and relying on conflicting statement from a coding standard doesn't provide much confidence in their teaching skill. The rest might be worth watching, but it has a very ill-written start.

Comment: Luckily we have a very old [Stack Overflow question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1265039/1014587), with a top answer that explains why it's littering the global namespace and examples of where it will go wrong if you do it anyway.

Comment: @Mast probably its not the best start but then again Jason is quite experienced . And his examples on using 3rd party libraries and namespace conflicts are spot on. These problems are real in large projects (I've worked with code bases involving tens of millions of lines of code and I've seen these things happen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `is_integral<float>()`, you are actualy calling the `operator bool`. The following calls the `operator()` instead:

```cpp
is_integral<float>()()
```

It can be seen more clear in the following code:

```cpp
    std::is_integral<int> x;
    if (x) { // operator bool
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << x << std::endl;  // operator bool
    std::cout << x() << std::endl; // operator()
    std::cout << std::is_integral<int>()() << std::endl; // operator()
```

`std::is_integral<float>()` is actually an anonymous object of type `std::is_integral<float>`.